# Electrical wiring hook up sequence

Tags: electrical, wiring, neutral, ground

I have found a box that as three duplex electric cables connecting.  The neutral (white) from wire 1 and wire 3 are connected.  The hot (black) from wire 1 is connected to wire 2, and the hot from wire 3 is also connected to wire 2 - this I don't understand - two hots feeding one cable. What would be the purpose?  Was there a reason why this would have been set up this way.  All the wiring only connects to lights and outlets, as far as we know, and is circa 1960s, but professionally done.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: Likely a duplicate:  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/159929/why-is-a-white-electrical-wire-connected-to-2-black-wires/159932#159932

Comment: **Cables** have a sheath and inside are multiple **wires**.  Using one word for the other creates a lot of confusion.  Normally I just [edit] to fix this, but your intent is ambiguous at a couple of points.  Also, where is this box located and what was it used for?  A receptacle (near floor)?  A switch?  In the ceiling for a lamp?

Comment: It almost sounds like a switch loop but after reading 3 times I do not understand the question 3 duplex do you mean 3 cables with 2 wires?